# To communicate with Service, what is the different between bindService() and create a instance of service?

Tags: android, android-service

To communicate with Service, what is the different between bindService() and create a instance of service? Why should need to use bindService() to communicate with service? I was confused by it.

(1)

```
public class BLEService extends Service {
    private static BLEService sService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       sService = this;
    }

    public static BLEService getInstance() {
        return sService;
    }
}

public class HeartRateActivity extends Activity {
    private BLEService mBLEService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBLEService = BLEService.getInstance();
    }
}
```

(2)

```
 public class BLEService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private BLEService mBLEService;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
      public MyleService getServerInstance() {
          return MyleService.this;
      }
    }
}

public class HeartRateActivity extends Activity {
    private BLEService mBLEService;
    private boolean mBounded;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, BLEService.class);
        bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBounded = false;
            mBLEService = null;
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBounded = true;
            LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)service;
            mBLEService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();

         }
    };

}
```

Thanks

Edit: Remove new operator in onCreate() of service

Answer (score 0):

You would *not* instantiate a Service object via its constructor using the `new` keyword.  A service is intended to be a long-running process that is not necessarily tied to the lifetime of the Activity that wants access to it.  As such, services are something that you use an Intent to signal to Android that you wish to run them in the same way that you use Intent objects to signal that you wish to start a new Activity.

Using `.bindService()` you can signal to Android that you want to attach to a running service (and to implicitly start that service if it isn't running already).  Once bound, you can communicate with the service via whichever interfaces it has available.